# Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки ENTER нажималась кнопка

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="ru">
        
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link
                href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap"
                rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
            <title>Документ</title>
        </head>
        
        <body>
        
            <div class="container">
                <form>
                <div class="search-box">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Введите"  value="Текст">
                    <button class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
        
                <div class="not-found">
                    <img src="images/404.png">
                    <p>Ой! Неверное местоположение :/</p>
                </div>
        
                <div class="weather-box">
                    <img src="">
                    <p class="temperature"></p>
                    <p class="description"></p>
                </div>
        
                <div class="weather-details">
                    <div class="humidity">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-water"></i>
                        <div class="text">
                            <span></span>
                            <p>Влажность</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wind">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-wind"></i>
                        <div class="text">
                            <span></span>
                            <p>Скорость ветра</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        
            </div>
        
            <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7c8801c017.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="index.js?v=8"></script>
        
        
        
   <script>
        const container = document.querySelector('.container');
        const search = document.querySelector('.search-box button');
        const weatherBox = document.querySelector('.weather-box');
        const weatherDetails = document.querySelector('.weather-details');
        const error404 = document.querySelector('.not-found');
        
        search.addEventListener('click', () => {
        
            const APIKey = '140175c2145ebbbae326d41de371ae86';
            const city = document.querySelector('.search-box input').value;
        
            if (city === '')
                return;
        
            fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&lang=ru&units=metric&appid=${APIKey}`)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json => {
        
                    if (json.cod === '404') {
                        container.style.height = '400px';
                        weatherBox.style.display = 'none';
                        weatherDetails.style.display = 'none';
                        error404.style.display = 'block';
                        error404.classList.add('fadeIn');
                        return;
                    }
        
                    error404.style.display = 'none';
                    error404.classList.remove('fadeIn');
        
                    const image = document.querySelector('.weather-box img');
                    const temperature = document.querySelector('.weather-box .temperature');
                    const description = document.querySelector('.weather-box .description');
                    const humidity = document.querySelector('.weather-details .humidity span');
                    const wind = document.querySelector('.weather-details .wind span');
        
                    switch (json.weather[0].main) {
                        case 'Clear':
                            image.src = 'images/clear.png';
                            break;
        
                        case 'Rain':
                            image.src = 'images/rain.png';
                            break;
        
                        case 'Snow':
                            image.src = 'images/snow.png';
                            break;
        
                        case 'Clouds':
                            image.src = 'images/cloud.png';
                            break;
        
                        case 'Haze':
                            image.src = 'images/mist.png';
                            break;
        
                        default:
                            image.src = '';
                    }
        
                    temperature.innerHTML = `${parseInt(json.main.temp)}<span>°C</span>`;
                    description.innerHTML = `${json.weather[0].description}`;
                    humidity.innerHTML = `${json.main.humidity}%`;
                    wind.innerHTML = `${parseInt(json.wind.speed)} КМ/Ч`;
        
                    weatherBox.style.display = '';
                    weatherDetails.style.display = '';
                    weatherBox.classList.add('fadeIn');
                    weatherDetails.classList.add('fadeIn');
                    container.style.height = '590px';
        
        
                });
        
        
        });
        
        </script>
        </body>
        
        </html>
```

Comment: А где у вас завершение тега ```<form>```?

Comment: Исправил⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Теги div и form пересекаются. И сделайте у кнопки ```type="button"```, а то она просто сабмитит текст.

Comment: Вы наверное имеете ввиду сабмит формы/отправка данных на сервер при нажатии кнопки Enter? Если да - исправьте заголовок, если нет - опишите подробнее задачу, что работает/не работает.

Answer (score 0):

В целом все правильно (не считая кривого HTML), просто добавьте еще один обработчик (не забудьте отписаться) и вынесите общую логику в отдельный метод.

```
input.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => myEventHandlerHere(event));
....
input.addEventListener("click", (event) => myEventHandlerHere(event))

myEventHandlerHere = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Отправляем форму на сервер
  } // Остальная логика
}
```

Comment: А как сделать чтобы страница не перезагружалась?

Comment: @sobolev - `event.preventDefault();`